# Silent install vcredist 2010 and do nothing if already installed

Tags: installation, vcredist

I need to install `vcredist_x86|x64.exe` 2010 from a batch file to be sure that all the needed dependencies are present in the PC.
If already installed, it should do nothing but it keeps showing the following GUI:

[image]

I tried all I've found in MS documentation and examples online but the result is always the same.
Tried `/q` `/quiet` `/qn` `/qb` `/passive` `/repair`.

Is it possbile to tell it to do nothing if already installed?

> EDIT

Important detail: I call the batch file from a javascript in a  Qt installer.

```
var vcredistCmd =  "@TargetDir@/vcredist.bat";
component.addElevatedOperation("Execute", vcredistCmd, targetDir);
```

The batch file:

```
%1\vcredist_x86.exe /q
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know the reason but I've found the solution.
Executing the file from the directory where it's located, solves the problem.

The batch file:

```
cd %1
vcredist_x86.exe /q
exit 0
```